# Mount / copy a file from host to Pod in kubernetes using minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm writing a `kubectl` configuration to start an image and copy a file to the container.
I need the file `Config.yaml` in the `/` so `/Config.yaml` needs to be a valid file.
I need that file in the Pod before it starts, so `kubectl cp` does not work.
I have the `Config2.yaml` in my local folder, and I'm starting the pod like:

```
kubectl apply -f pod.yml
```

Here follows my pod.yml file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: python
spec:
   containers:
   - name: python
     image: mypython
     volumeMounts:
     - name: config
       mountPath: /Config.yaml
   volumes:
   - name: config
     hostPath:
       path: Config2.yaml
       type: File
```

If I try to use like this it also fails:

```
      - name: config-yaml
        mountPath: /
        subPath: Config.yaml
        #readOnly: true
```

Comment: May I know from where you get ```Config.yaml``` file?

Comment: @hariK It is a file I'll have in my machine in the moment I create the pod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need the information contained in the config.yaml to be present in the pod from the time it is created, use a configMap instead.

Create a configMap that contains all the data stored in the config.yaml and mount that into the correct path in the pod. This would not work for read/write, but works wonderfully for read-only data

Comment: The problem on using a configMap is that my Config.yaml is not just a key / value config, ot has a slightly more complex structure, so I don't think I'm going to be able to create the configMap.

Comment: You can put arbitrary content and even whole files into ConfigMap content (up to a modest-but-practical size limit).

Comment: Your 'key' in this case would be the name of the file and the value is the full content of said file

Answer (score 0):

You can try `postStart` lifecycle handler here to validate the file before pod starts.

Please refer [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    resources: {}
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /config.yaml
      name: config
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "apt update && apt install yamllint -y && yamllint /config.yaml"]
  volumes:
  - name: config
    hostPath:
      path: /tmp/config.yaml
      type: File 
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

If `config.yaml` is invalid. Pod won't start.